# cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated not working with IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my code, its working fine when it comes to Android. But when im taking a build for IOS its not working.

package.json

```
"cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated": {
        "ANDROID_FCM_VERSION": "19.0.0",
        "ANDROID_GRADLE_TOOLS_VERSION": "4.2.0",
        "ANDROID_GOOGLE_SERVICES_VERSION": "4.3.3",
        "ANDROID_DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_ICON": "@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      },
```

```
import { FCM } from 'cordova-plugin-fcm-with-dependecy-updated/ionic/ngx'; 
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private fcm: FCM) { 
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
   this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.fcm.getToken().then(token => { 
        console.log(token); 
        EnvironmentConfig.token = token; 
        this.commonService.updateFCMToken(token, userId).subscribe( 
          async data => {
            // 
          },
          error => { 
            
          }
        ); 
      }); 
    })
    .catch(e => console.log('ErrorInitFCM', e))
}
```

In IOS i followed following procedure and still its not working.

Added pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '7.8.0' to podfile.

podfile

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Project' do
    project 'Project.xcodeproj'
    pod 'Firebase'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '7.8.0'
end
```

Removed Podfile.lock, Pods, Project.xwcworkspace
pod install on IOS folder.
Then Podfile.lock, Pods, Project.xwcworkspace Generated.
Opened xcode using Project.xwcworkspace

PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/. Added to userdefined settings to the build settings.

Then Archive Project.

It showing error 'Firebase.h' file not found [Click here to view error after build in xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tXdH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install cocoa pods before installing the fcm plugin using the following command:
`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Also `cordova run ios` may work better than building the application directly from xcode.